# Событие перерисовки кастомного маркера в яндекс картах

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Вопрос, вероятно, будет без кода, ибо надо просто понять, что использовать.

Ситуация следующая. На карту с помощью менеджера объектов загружаются точки. Вместо обычного маркера создается свой: `ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(....)`.

Далее пользователь может точки выбирать и добавлять в список, а к кастомному лайауту маркера добавляется класс `selected`, который влияет на его визуально отображение (читай - меняет цвет маркера в стилях).

И вот тут загвоздка. При некоторых условиях макет маркера перерисосывается. Например, когда открывается баллун, то маркер скрывается, а когда баллун закрывается маркер пересоздается. Либо когда маркер уходит далеко за область отображения карты, а потом вернем карту назад то он опять тоже создается заново. В общем говоря, менеджер все в памяти не держит и порой пересоздает макеты.
Как следствие - теряется класс `selected`.

И вот теперь вопрос - как отловить событие, когда маркер пересоздается, чтобы проверить его наличие в списке выбранных и вернуть ему класс `.selected`.

Answer (score 2):

В общем говоря, задача свелась к более простой. Не надо из-вне управлять классами маркера, а в `properties` внести счетчик того, добавлен маркер в список или нет (может быт добавлен несколько раз). Далее соответственно это учесть в шаблоне маркера, добавляя (или нет) нужный класс. Таким образом, при каждом перестроении он сам подхватывает данные, когда карта его перерисовывает.

Тут правда встает вопрос о том,  как принудительно перерисовать маркер при его выборе, но пока что классы добавляются внешним кодом.

Итак, если кому-то пригодится, то небольшие фрагменты кода по проблеме.

Создаем карту, загружаем данные

```
map = new ymaps.map(....);
mgr = new ymaps.ObjectManager(...);

$.getJSON("/path/to/points.json", function(data){
    
});
```

в загрузке определяем макет

```
let mark = '<div class="camera {{ properties.src }} {% if properties.selected %}selected{% endif %}" id="mm-{{ properties.sid }}">...</div>';
let markerLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(mark);
```

тут `properties.selected` это счетчик добавлений точки в список.

Далее генерим информацию по точкам и добавляем их на карту

```
 let points = data.map(function(a, idx){
          return {
               type: "Feature",
               id: idx,
               geometry: { .... },

               properties: {
                   .....
                   sid: ... ,
                   selected: 0, // <--- поле счетчика
               },
               options: {
                  iconLayout: markerLayout,    // <---- макет
                  iconShape : { .... }         // активная область для кликов
                  openBalloonOnClick: false,
               }
            };
      });

 mgr.add( { type: "FeatureCollection", features: points });
 map.geoObjects.add(mgr);
```

Тут (к вопросу  не относится, но для полноты картины) при клике в маркер открываем баллун, а если клик с контролом/шифтом, то добавляем в список

```
mgr.objects.events.add('click', function(e){
    let oid = e.get('objectId');
    let o = mgr.objects.getById(oid);
    if(o.geometry.type !== 'Point') return false;

    let oe = e.get('domEvent').originalEvent;
    if(oe.ctrlKey || oe.shiftKey) {
        model.add(o);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        mgr.objects.balloon.open(oid);
    }

    return false;
});
```

вызов `model.add(o)` тут увеличивает счетчики, добавляет начальный `.selected` (вот тут бы дернуть перерисовку вручную, и класс бы добавился самостоятельно).  Формально перерисоваться он должен при изменений не `properties` а `options`, но там нам вроде менять нечего.

```
  function add(o){
      let sid = o.properties.sid;
      let target = "#mm-" + sid;
      $(target).addClass('selected');

      o.properties.selected++;
      this.selected[sid] = true;
      this.modified = true;
  }
```

при удалении из списка делается аналогичный `selected--` и `removeClass()` при достижении 0.